# horizontal controlgroup with togglebuttons in gwt bootstrap

Tags: java, user-interface, gwt-bootstrap

I'm trying to build a gwt bootstrap form with some boolean values.
As they are multiple selectable its usually checkboxes. That works.

But I find checkboxes ugly and would prefer another look and feel, for example buttongroup with togglebuttons.

Buttongroup don't work in a form, I think because they are no form elements.

What are my options? How can I realize a number of boolean form elements nicely?

Regards
Markus

Answer (score 0):

`ButtonGroup` does work in `Form`s. Here is some sample code:

```
<b:Form>
    <b:ControlLabel>Label name</b:ControlLabel>
    <b:TextBox placeholder="Type something…" />
    <b:HelpBlock>Example block-level help text here.</b:HelpBlock>
    <b:CheckBox> Check me out</b:CheckBox>
    <b:ButtonGroup>
        <b:Button toggle="true">Sample1</b:Button>
        <b:Button toggle="true">Sample2</b:Button>
        <b:Button toggle="true">Sample3</b:Button>
        <b:Button toggle="true">Sample4</b:Button>
        <b:Button toggle="true">Sample5</b:Button>
    </b:ButtonGroup>
    <b:SubmitButton addStyleNames="btn">Submit</b:SubmitButton>
</b:Form>
```

Comment: @Spooky Thanks for the edit mate. New here so making mistakes at start.